# print from mobile computer to zebra printer via Bluetooth comunication

Tags: c#, bluetooth, zebra-printers, windows-mobile-6.5, smart-device

I am developing a project for Windows Mobile 6.5 MC75A Mobile computer. I connectd my MC75A Mobile computer to the Zebra printer(ZEBRA qln420) via Bluetooth.

I am developing application in vb.net.in my project i added **`PrinterCE.NetCF.dll`** and i copyed the same dll into windows folder in mobile device. in application print button click i given code like this:

```
 Dim prce As PrinterCE

        Try
            'No License Key for evaluation
            prce = New PrinterCE(PrinterCE.EXCEPTION_LEVEL.ABORT_JOB, "YOURLICENSEKEY")

            prce.SelectPrinter(True)

            prce.DrawText("Hello World")
            prce.EndDoc()
        Catch exc As PrinterCEException
            prce.ShutDown()
            MessageBox.Show("PrinterCE Exception", "Exception")
        Finally
            prce.ShutDown()
        End Try
```

but this is not working fine ..throwing error.while clicking print button.how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the SDK from Zebra? It walks you through adding it to your project and has examples for connecting to and printing using BT.

https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/link-os/link-os-sdk.html

Comment: sir what u mean by Did you try using the SDK from Zebra..i am begginer..can u elaborate?

Comment: Download the SDK from the link above. Look through the documentation on how to install it into your development environment. Run the demos. Look at the source code from the demos. Create your solution.

Comment: sir i have downloaded form correspodnig link.but that sample code is not running? if you don't mind can i tell the error?

Comment: You need to install the runtime (PrCE_NetCF.dll) for the mobile device first: http://www.fieldsoftware.com/PrinterCE_NetCF_download.htm

Comment: The SDK uses the .Net CompactFramework. Microsoft® .NET Compact Framework v3.5 http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E3821449-3C6B-42F1-9FD9-0041345B3385&displaylang=en